# Should every Fatty still come with two Walkers?

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

In Zombicide, whenever a Fatty is spawned, it comes with two Walkers as an "escort".

However, I couldn't pinpoint this rule in the Zombicide Black Plague manual. Is that still the case?

For further clarification, my question arose from a passage from the translated manual that came in my box. In the [official english rulebook](https://zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-black-plague.pdf), on the end of page 24, there is the following excerpt:

> The Fatty joins one group of Walkers, and a second Fatty is added to the other group.

In the [pr-BR translated version](https://d23s8aksxnlj6y.cloudfront.net/system/game/assets/attachments/000/003/837/original/ZF-BP-RULEBOOK_pt-BR_v06_low.pdf?1466544831), published by Galápago Jogos, however, the same paragraph is phrased in the following form:

> O Balofo se junta a um dos grupos de Lerdos, e um segundo
>   Balofo é adicionado ao outro grupo (esse novo Balofo não vem com
>   Lerdos extras).

Which roughly translates to (emphasis mine):

> The Fatty joins one group of Walkers, and a second Fatty is added to the other group **(this new Fatty does not come with extra Walkers)**.

Which implies on regular spawns it does come accompanied. But this is certainly a silly translation error, that always happens with pr-BR things. I should've checked the original manual first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While explicitly pointed out in the Zombicide rulebook and extra attention called to the additional Walkers, there is no such note in the Black Plague rulebook.

Since no rule requires it, and these are distinct games with separate rulesets, you do not add the two Walkers escort.

Answer (score -2):

I know that this is a super old question but the correct answer doesn't seem to be given. The rule in which you are referring to is for splitting groups, not spawning fatties. Fatties have no rule requiring them to have extra walkers with them.

Comment: The rule for fatties coming with walkers is in the original (modern setting) zombicide, Nij's answer was correct in saying that while that is a rule from the original game, this is a separate game, which has a lot of the same rules, but not this one.