# Green Horde: Do Orc Fatties spawn with 2x Orc Walkers?

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

The answer to [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33577/should-every-fatty-still-come-with-two-walkers) pertaining to Black Plague suggests that Orc Fatties *don't* get an escort because it's not specifically stated in the rule book; as [Green Horde](https://www.zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-zombicide-green-horde.pdf) is also a stand-alone core set, is it safe to assume this holds true for it, as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you can safely assume that, because it is not in the [rules](https://www.zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-black-plague.pdf) (I checked all the instances of fatties and the relevant sections) they do not get an escort.

But if you think that is too easy, you can always add them.